# Ubuntu does not boot, kernel panic - not syncung: Fatal exeption in interrupt

Tags: ubuntu

My VM box all of a sudden stopped working. When I start the system the following message appears.

[image]

Then either initialization options retrieve the same error as bellow.

[image]

I suspect it is because I ran out of space on my VM box storage because I'd been receiving a notification telling on the short space (500mb left if I remember correctly) but unfortunately I could not make any remove command on the grub shell.

I do not mind losing the entire machine, apart from my www/ folder, so some possible solutions came to my mind and would be much appreciated:

Delete some files from the machine - restricted to the actions of the grub.
Manage to recover my www/ folder to another Linux ubuntu server.
Be able to get to cmd and perform the apt-get autoremove - or something similar.
Any other idea is also welcomed (given the desperation state I am in now)

Comment: I cannot currently see the images (I am partially visually impaired, as are others here).. Can you describe them? Or if they are plain text, transcribe the text and post the plain text? As for recovery, can you mount a live-cd image in the VM and use the recovery mode/emergency console the same way you would with a physical machine?

Comment: Sorry, I just edit with the images inline. Thanks for your comment, about your last question, I am not sure about it, maybe I can try, but to be honest I have no idea how.

Comment: Putting the images inline does not help... I cannot SEE and READ them. My screen reader just "speaks" the plain text as: "... following message appears <image display> then either ...". It literally says "image display", since it cannot "read" an image. But if you write a description/summary of the image as plain text, it will speak that part.

Comment: Regarding the question itself, you said "VM box"... Can you explain what you mean? Are you running a VM on your computer via something like VMWare or Oracle VirtualBox? Or are you using a web/cloud based VM from a paid subscription? If it is your own machine running the VM, create/download an ISO image of any LiveCD, and instruct our VM manager program to boot the VM from he ISO instead of the virtual hard drive. There are many web pages available on how to recover a broken Linux machine; either a physical machine or a VM in something like VirtualBox, by using a LiveCD.

Comment: And finally, you said low on disk space, only 500MB. You are correct in that being a clue on what is probably the problem. The base system needs enough free "workspace" on the drive to boot. The /var and /tmp directories, for example, and the various log files. There are alternatives, such as using a RAM disk in embedded systems or ReadOnly LiveCD's, but I am assuming you did _not_ set up something like that from the beginning. A full discussion of all of this is too long for comments, so you will have to search web pages for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GRUB shell is strictly read-only, so it will not be able to make any persistent changes. So the idea of removing things in the GRUB shell will not work.

The messages in your screenshot look like multiple kernel panic messages jammed together. Because one of the lines says `Lost 677 message(s)!`, it is likely that the first panic message (that might be the root cause of the others) is already scrolled off the screen and is unreachable, even if you could still use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to scroll the console display.

As already mentioned in the comments, you might get yourself an ISO image of a live-CD, upload that to the system that hosts your VM, and then use the VM management functions (either in the VM console or in a separate GUI) to "insert" the ISO image into a virtual CD drive and tell the VM to boot from it. The exact details will depend on the virtualization technology used: if your VM is in commercial hosting, this is something the technical support of your hosting provider should be able to help you with.

If it's cheap commercial hosting, the VMs might be restricted to using a limited number of standard installation images. In that case, you might have to create a second VM with a working OS, and then use the VM management functions to detach the virtual system disk from the failing VM and present it (temporarily) as a second disk on the new, good VM. This will allow you to access the disk of the failing VM: you'll just have to mount its partitions to a separate location.

For example, if the new good VM's own system disk would be `/dev/sda` and the disk from the bad VM would now be presented as `/dev/sdb` on the good VM, you could use `lsblk` or `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` to identify the partitions, then `mkdir /rescue` and `mount /dev/sdbN /rescue` to mount partition N from the bad VM's disk to `/rescue` for the purpose of recovering data from it, or even to identify and fix any problems on that disk.

Comment: That sounds good, thanks for your answer.  Do you think that it will be possible to rescue even with the limitation of space on my VM?

Comment: If the space notification was from within the Ubuntu VM, then the new VM will have its own disk with a separate disk space allocation, and once you gain access to the bad VM you will be able to delete things if necessary. If the notification came from the VM management system, you might need to talk to your hosting provider to get more space, at least temporarily for solving your problems.